# How can I combine multiple Postgres database dumps into a single database?

Tags: postgresql

I have ~100 Postgres `.dump` from different sources. They all have the same schema, just a single table, and a few hundred to a few hundred thousand rows. However, the data was collected at different locations and now needs to all be combined.

So I'd like to merge all the rows from all the databases into one single database, ignoring the ID key. What would be a decent way to do this? I may collect more data in the future from more sources, so it's likely to be a process I need to repeat.

Comment: In future, try collecting data in a more practical format than a database dump. A dump is designed to reproduce a database exactly. It's not good for merging, etc. I suspect your best bet will be to restore each dump to a staging DB then use ETL tools (CloverETL, Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, etc) or custom scripting to merge into the main DB. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if needed use pg_restore to convert the dumps into SQL.

run the SQL dump trhough

```
 sed '/^COPY .* FROM stdin;$/,/^\\.$/ p;d'
```

as there is only one table in your data that will give you the copy command needed to load the data  send that to your database to load the data.